# JQueryUI Droppable position with clone helper enabled

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to simply copy copy images (ul>li>img) from one container to other with clone property enabled (Clone should be copied and original remains at original position.

Problem is my droppable container should behave as canvas and I need exact drop position for that, which I'm not getting.

Code links are:
HTML: http://pastebin.com/vPW318J1

CSS: Not allowing to put more than 2 links pastebin.com/6EaiwSEQ

JavaScript: http://pastebin.com/ZuCLc4ma

Is there any way to get exact drop coordinates, if possible with respect to #canvas?

Thanks for reading and any answer.

Regards,

Kapil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it took sometime but finally I was able to fix it.

I updated above links with latest and working code, in case someone else stuck with same problem.

Kapil.